# Cant display static image in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I can't display image, image is in the same folder.

```
  each user,i in users //users data loop
    h2=user.name
    .card
      img(src='img_rr_01.jpg', alt='Avatar', style='width:100%') // Image 
      |   
      .container
        h4
          b=user.email
        |  
          p=user.name
```

Comment: are you specifying your public assets folder by mentioning something like this - `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../public")));`?

Comment: Yeah, I have it in app.js file

Comment: ok. Then your static file's paths should normally be starting with `/` and then follow the path as it is in your `public` folder. e.g. if your image is in `public/images` folder, then update your src to be `/images/img_rr_01.jpg`. Please note that you need not mention `public` folder in your src.

Comment: okay, perfect fix

Comment: I have added the comments as an answer. Please mark it as accepted if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are specifying your public assets folder by mentioning something like this -

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../public")));
```

Then your static file's paths should normally be starting with `/` and then follow the path as it is in your public folder. e.g. if your image is in `public/images` folder, then update your `src` to be `/images/img_rr_01.jpg`.

Please note that you need not mention `public` folder in your src.

Answer (score 0):

Express is not going to serve anything that you don't give permission to. You have to give permission by using express.static middleware.

> To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express

For more details refer to https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like below in app.js you can directly specify the folder in which you have stored the images.

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```